# Freeing memory after IBOutlet (UIImageView)

Tags: ios, memory-management, iboutlet

I have an `IBOutlet` `UIImageView*` in `ViewController`. After releasing Controller (I don't need it anymore), `UIImageView`* has retainCount is 2 (code has no any retains), and even after two times of release [i think, this totally wrong] (in Controllers `dealloc`) `UIImageView` memory still allocated . Why it happens and my question is - how I can to totally freed memory after dealloc `UIViewController` with `IBOutlets`?

```
@interface GRULogInController (){
    IBOutlet UIImageView* bgImage;
}
@end
@implementation GRULogInController
....

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    NSLog(@"%d", bgImage.retainCount); // Shows 2 !!!
    [bgImage release];
    [bgImage release]; // Object releases but memory not freed (It shown in Instruments)

    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [self viewDidUnload];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: New recommendations from apple, don't use viewDidUnload to release objects. dealloc is enough or any other appropriate method.

Comment: Ok, takin a note. But this thing is not solves problem.

Comment: true, that's why I only wrote a comment =)

Answer (score 1):

First of all take a look at this link. [whentouseretaincount.com](http://whentouseretaincount.com)
It just doesn't tell anything useful.

Second, iOS purges viewControllers when it needs the memory and not immediately after you releasing a viewController.
You shouldn't release the imageView twice, let the viewController handle that.

Another thing is that viewDidUnload is deprecated and you should do your code in dealloc instead.

Comment: I'm shouldn't - I know it. But I need to release memory. And, i think, if I am not using ARC - then I can be able to manage memory by myself. Is it right?

Comment: About retainCount. Is there any other tool to identify retains?

Comment: No there is no other tool. So what do you really need? You wan't to manually free memory? That's not possible. You have to wait till the system purges things. Yes, using MRR means to manage the memory by yourself, but that doesn't mean that you can directly free memory.

Comment: *correction of "No there is no other tool": By that i meant, that there is not method or anything to check by code. **But** you can let the static analyzer check your code and it will tell you all your memory mistakes.

Comment: The Static analyzer shows that is no errors. I want to free memory for few reasons. Main thing is to remove useless objects (such as huge pictures) at the moment when I need and not then when it can take processor time, which should be used for working of other parts of the program. I agree - who do not need this flow APC and other garbage collectors is useful but not in my case.

Comment: If the static analyzer doesn't show anything, then you are good to go.

Comment: You did it right by releasing the image one time and you removed with this useless objects. The thing is, that iOS will automatically free the things you don't need once it thinks it needs the space. You did everything correct with your code and don't bother yourself that there is still a pointer to this image.

Comment: `If the static analyzer doesn't show anything, then you are good to go.`That's not true. Static Analyser won't be able to detect circular referencing for example, so beware about that.

Answer (score 0):

> UIImageView* has retainCount is 2

How do you know? Don't rely on `retainCount` please. Still:

1 - Your `IBOutlet` reference.

2 - Your `UIView` that as strong reference to its children UI elements.

So there you go, your retainCount 2 (in theory).

Use instruments to check if you are having Memory Leaks. Also, as Frederik pointed don't use `viewDidUnload`, no need for it anymore.

Comment: 1- Agree, 2- I have no @property (strong) in my code as You can see, I have just a pointer to the outlet and it should not retain

Comment: 2- You don't handle this, it's internal. Your `UIViewController`'s root `UIView` has a reference to its children.